# Catching original exception when using async synchronously

Tags: c#, locking, async-await

I'm using the [PCLStorage](https://github.com/dsplaisted/pclstorage) library to access files on multiple platforms.
This library only offers asynchronous methods. I'm using these methods inside a `lock` block so they can run synchronously. I'm using `.Result` to wait for the result of call. I'm trying to catch the exception inside this lock, but because the `AggregateException` is thrown, it won't get to my catch block.

```
lock (this)
{
    try
    {
        IFile file = folder.GetFileAsync (FileName).Result;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        //won't be catched
    }
}
```

How can I catched the original exception thrown when inside a `lock`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To block the current thread while waiting for the `Task` to complete, and get the unwrapped `Task` exception (if any), you can do:

```
try
{
    var file = folder.GetFileAsync(FileName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    // Will be catched :)
}
```

If you block on the `.Result` property instead, you need to catch an `AggregateExcetpion` and inspect its inner exception.

To get more information on this, I can recommend Stephen Cleary's blog series on  `A Tour of Task`. In [Part 6: Results](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/12/a-tour-of-task-part-6-results.html), he writes:

> **`Result`**
>   Like `Wait`, `Result` will synchronously block the calling thread until the task completes. (...) Furthermore, `Result` will wrap
>   any task exceptions inside an `AggregateException`. This usually just
>   complicates the error handling.
>
> **`GetAwaiter().GetResult()`** The `GetAwaiter` member was added to `Task` and `Task<T>` in .NET 4.5, and it’s available as an extension method on
>   .NET 4.0 using the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` NuGet package. (...)  In
>   general, I try my best to avoid synchronously blocking on an
>   asynchronous task. However, there are a handful of situations where I
>   do violate that guideline. In those rare conditions, my preferred
>   method is `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` *because it preserves the task
>   exceptions instead of wrapping them in an `AggregateException`*.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I catched the original exception thrown when inside a lock?

You don't.  You'll have to catch the aggregate exception, unwrap it, and see what the inner exceptions are.  If it's an exception that you can't handle then you can always re-throw it.

> I'm using these methods inside a `lock` block so they can run asyncronously

Using `lock` doesn't make it asynchronous.  And on top of that, you're synchronously blocking it, so you're not even doing that.  This quote just makes no sense at all.

Comment: Yes I indeed ment that the code inside the lock was synchronous, not asyncronous.

Comment: @Waaghals Using a `lock` doesn't make it synchronous.  It exists to prevent a critical section of code from having multiple invocations running at once.  It has nothing to do with asynchrony.